# select column name dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm bit new in writing procedures in sql. So please help me with this requirement.

I have one table which has column names and I wanted to dynamically select the column name to retrieve data from other columns.

For example

```
    Id  colname     Name    Age Salary
     1  Name, Age   Raghu   23  20000
     2  Salary      Raghav  45  30000
     3  Age         Fizal   33  20000

    NewId   colName     Values
       1    Name,Age    Raghu, 23
       2    Salary      20000
       3    Age         33
```

Here in #table1, using colname I wanted to pull data from other columns(Name, Age, Salary) and create #table2 as it is in the above example. I would like to know the best approach to implement the same.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you're doing it this way? Why not just write the actual statement you want? Or return all the columns, and have your application use those columns it needs?

Comment: I'm trying to know best approach. Do you mean to say return the desired columns using LINQ c# is the best way to do than the procedure approach

Comment: No, he's trying to say that you don't have to fill another table if you already have a table like _table1_. Just do a query like `SELECT Id AS NewId, colname AS colName, CASE colname WHEN 'Name, Age' THEN Name + ', ' + Age WHEN 'Salary' THEN Salary WHEN 'Age' THEN Age END AS [Values] FROM #table1`. This is provided that you only have those values in `colname`. If it has to be dynamic then you'll have to dynamically build the SQL statement to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can that be done? Yes. But since you're asking the best way to do it, I would say that doing something like this in general, is not good practice. Overloading columns in SQL is rarely a good idea. Overloading in this case meaning storing more than one value in a single field, such as `[values]` containing `Raghu, 23`. What benefit do you gain from concatenating them together that you couldn't also have by just leaving them as separate columns?

My suggestion is just return all the columns, regardless of the `Id`, and do away with the `colname` field. Then your query is as trivial as something like this:

```
select 
    Id, 
    Name,
    Age,
    Salary
from #Data

/* Returns
Id   Name     Age   Salary
---- -------- ----- -----------
1    Raghu    23    20000
2    Raghav   45    30000
3    Fizal    33    20000
*/
```

Yes, you'll get back columns you don't necessarily need for some for those rows, such as `Salary` for `Id = 1`, or `Name` and `Age` for `id = 2`, but so what?

Assuming it's an entitlement thing, and you can't just show all columns for all people, you could maintain a list of the entitled mappings (either in SQL or your application) and only render those they're entitled to.

**Alternatively** if you absolutely *cannot* have data going over the wire a potential user isn't entitled to, you could still do it in SQL, but just null out the columns you don't want to return, as opposed to trying to serialize all the entitled values into a single field. The end result is the same, but it's far easier to do that than dynamically serialize all that data.

A procedure to do that might look something like this. It only works for the three columns you mentioned, but you could add more parameters, or have it accept a list of fields, an XML document of fields, or a table valued parameter of fields. I didn't go those approaches since they're a bit more involved to implement, but this should get the idea across

```
create table #Data
(
    Id int primary key,
    Name nvarchar(50),
    Age int,
    Salary int
)

insert into #Data (Id, Name, Age, Salary)
values 
    (1, 'Raghu', 23, 20000),
    (2, 'Raghav', 45, 30000),
    (3, 'Fizal', 33, 20000)

go

create proc #GetData
    @Id int,
    @ShowName bit,
    @ShowAge bit,
    @ShowSalary bit
as

select
    ID,
    Name = iif(@ShowName = 1, Name, null),
    Age = iif(@ShowAge = 1, Age, null),
    Salary = iif(@ShowSalary = 1, Salary, null)
from #Data
where Id = @Id
```

You would then call the procedure like this:

```
-- ID: 1
exec #GetData @Id = 1, @ShowName = 1, @ShowAge = 1, @ShowSalary = 0
/*
ID    Name    Age         Salary
----- ------- ----------- -----------
1     Raghu   23          NULL
*/
-- ID: 2
exec #GetData @Id = 2, @ShowName = 0, @ShowAge = 0, @ShowSalary = 1
/*
ID    Name    Age         Salary
----- ------- ----------- -----------
2     NULL    NULL        30000
*/
-- ID: 3
exec #GetData @Id = 3, @ShowName = 0, @ShowAge = 1, @ShowSalary = 0 
/*
ID    Name    Age         Salary
----- ------- ----------- -----------
3     NULL    33          NULL
*/
```